# Unable to mount hostPath with Docker Desktop on Linux

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

i need mount an existing local directory into a pod with Docker Desktop Kubernetes, I use this yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: my-image:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "0"
            cpu: "0"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: api-code
          mountPath: /opt/app/api
      volumes:
      - name: api-code
        hostPath:
          path: /home/my-home/repositories/my-project/app/api
```

Local folder `/home/my-home/repositories/my-project/app/api` exists and there are files, into pod instead, exists `/opt/app/api` but is empty, `/home` directory is correctly listed in the section `File sharing` of Docker Desktop

**UPDATE:**
Same configuration work with microk8s

Comment: Hi hellb0y77, I was wondering if you got the workaround of this problem, I am facing same problem with Docker Desktop on Ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it works if you add `/host_mnt` at the beginning of the host path (see [issue](https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/124) on the Docker Desktop for Linux repo).

That is, instead of:

```yaml
path: /home/my-home/repositories/my-project/app/api
```

use:

```yaml
path: /host_mnt/home/my-home/repositories/my-project/app/api
```

Full YAML with modification:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: my-image:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "0"
            cpu: "0"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: api-code
          mountPath: /opt/app/api
      volumes:
      - name: api-code
        hostPath:
          path: /host_mnt/home/my-home/repositories/my-project/app/api
```